# DirectWrite GDI interop: Simple way to draw text using an `IDWriteFontFace`

Tags: c++, windows, gdi, direct2d, directwrite

I have a device context which has some font selected into it, and I would like to `DrawText` on an `ID2D1RenderTarget`.

Currently, I go the following route to acchieve this:

- Obtain an `IDWriteFontFace` via `CreateFontFaceFromHdc`.
- Obtain an `IDWriteFont` from the `IDWriteFontFace` via the default system font collection (which I get via `GetSystemFontCollection` - see the next step).
- Obtain an `IDWriteTextFormat` via `CreateTextFormat`, supplying the parameters specified in the `IDWriteFont` and specifying `nullptr` as `fontCollection`, indicating that I would like to use the default system font collection.
- Pass the `IDWriteTextFormat` to `DrawText`.

What I find strange about this is that I already have an `IDWriteFontFace` in the first step, and apparently have to "go back" and ask a font collection for an `IDWriteFont`, just to pass that to a `DrawTextFormat`, which can then be used to `DrawText`. This seems unnecessarily complicated - especially since to draw the text, the system probably has to go down to a `IDWriteFontFace` anyway, right?

I found `DrawGlyphRun`, but this takes e.g. a `baselineOrigin`, which I would have to compute beforehand (not to mention the `glyphRun` itself).

Isn't there a simpler way to draw text onto an `ID2D1RenderTarget` if I already have an `IDWriteFontFace`?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what will happen in case when selected font comes from AddFontMemResourceEx(). In this case it won't be available in system collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the only way, like you described. You go back to construct text format instance, and then use it for DirectWrite-style rendering. `DrawGlyphRun` is a low level method, you can use it of course, but you'll have to implement a lot of layout logic yourself, and that's something to avoid. Generally speaking `DrawText` is the least efficient method of rendering with Direct2D, better way is to create layout object once and use it every time you need to redraw.

Comment: Thanks you! But generating a `IDWriteTextLayout` requires an `IDWriteTextFormat` in the first place, so I can not use the `IDWriteFontFace` there, can I?

Comment: Yes, you'll need format object too of course. Complexity comes from the fact that you're using GDI interop in a first place. To be able to use DrawText you only need to know family name, and font properties. And again, see my other comment, I'm not sure how it works for memory font resources, it might be a limiting factor too.